# How to call javascript function for field in grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, itemtemplate

The amount column in the grid should be coma formatted like 2,000,000. How to call javascript comma function from grid bound field and return the value to grid.
Javascript:

```
 function Comma(data)
 {
   //coma formatting to amount

    return data; //return the coma formatted amount variable
 }
```

aspx side:

```
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Amount" DataField="Amount" onclientclick=Comma(Amount)  />
```

or

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" >
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Amount") %>'  
         OnClientClick="Comma(Amount)"> </asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its better to send the amount as integer/number, and make the format on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below in your `.aspx` file.

```
OnClientClick=<%# "Comma('" + Eval("Amount") + "')" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also format the number directly in the GridView as a correct decimal. Then you don't need to call a javascript function for every row.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:N0}", Eval("Amount")) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Or as currency

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Amount")) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```